# Go app cannot catch signals

Tags: linux, unix, go, signals

Sending signals from kill on linux,
`kill -s 2 <PID>` or `kill -s 15 <PID>`

The code is:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
   "os"
   "os/signal"
)

func main() {
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigs)
    go func() {
        sig := <-sigs
        fmt.Println(sig)
    }()
    fmt.Println("waiting")
    <-done
    fmt.Println("exiting")
}
```

The program does not handle signals,
only `CTRL+C` works well.

Comment: to find the PID running ```ps aux | grep go```

Comment: Your program works for me. Please specify what behaviour you were expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func()` is terminated after receiving the first signal, I think `CTLR+C` was the first one when you try. It works when it is wrapped in a loop.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
   "os"
   "os/signal"
)

func main() {
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    done := make(chan bool, 1)
    signal.Notify(sigs)
    go func() {
        for {
            sig := <-sigs
            fmt.Println(sig)
        }
    }()
    fmt.Println("waiting")
    <-done
    fmt.Println("exiting")
}
```

Tested with;

```
$ kill -15 <pid>
$ kill -2 <pid>
$ kill -10 <pid>
$ kill -1 <pid>
$ kill -10 <pid>

$ ./signal 
waiting
terminated
interrupt
user defined signal 1
hangup
user defined signal 1
```